# Static image calibration

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera-calibration

I am capturing static images of particulate biological materials on the millimeter scale, and then processing them in MATLAB. My routine is working well so far, but I am using a rudimentary calibration procedure where I include some coins in the image, automatically find them based on their size and circularity, count their pixels, and then remove them. This allows me to generate a calibration line with input "area-mm^2" and output "Area- pixels," which I then use to convert the pixel area of the particles into physical units of millimeters squared.

My question is: is there a better calibrant object that I can use, such as a stage graticule or "phantom" as some people seem to call them? Do you know where I could purchase such a thing? I can't even seem to find a possible vendor. Is there another rigorous way to approach this problem without using calibrant objects in the field of view?

Thanks in advance.

Clay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image calibration is always done using features of knowns size or distance.
You could calculate the scale based on nominal specifications but your imaging equipment will always have some production tolerances, your object distance is only known to a certain accuracy...
So it's always safer and simpler to actually calibrate your scale.

As a calibrant you can use anything that meets your requirements. If you know the size well enough and if you are able to extract it's dimensions in pixels properly you can use it...

I don't know your requirements and your budget, but if you want something very precise and fancy you can use glass masks.
There are temperature stable glass slides that are coated with chrome for example. There are many companies that produce such masks customized (IMT AG, BVM maskshop, ...) Also most optics lab equipment suppliers have such things on stock. Edmund Optics, Newport, ...

Comment: Great! Yes, I want to include an object or objects in the field of view for my images that has a known dimension. Previously I used standard US dimes, which were easy to identify based on their circularity. However, I am looking for something a bit more "official" and preferably traceable to an accepted standard. You've given me a lot of great leads to companies that may be able to provide such a target.